# Is there a way to type alias std::make_pair function in cpp 11 to abc::make_pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, alias

I am trying to type alias `std::make_pair` function to use it as `abc::make_pair` function.

```
auto(*make_pair)() = std::make_pair<T1, T2>;

namespace abc
{
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    using array = std::array<T, N>;

    template<class T1, class T2>
    auto(*make_pair)() = std::make_pair<T1, T2>;
}
```

error:

```
variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14 [-Werror]
```

Comment: `using std::make_pair;`, perhaps?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you mean `abc::make_pair`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, I meant putting `using std::make_pair;` into `abc` namespace. [Like this](https://rextester.com/MPUO29568)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see.

Comment: Thanks.. I was unnecessarily complicating it.

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace abc
{
  using std::make_pair;
}
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/MPUO29568)